# How can I get Octave to change the variables in my input files?

Tags: sed, octave

I am trying to get Octave to change variables in my input files like it would if I were using the command line in Ubuntu. I've stripped this back to a simple case where I get it to change '1111' to the string Naer_str and '2222' to the string sigma_str; printing the result to a new file. 1111 and 2222 are both present in the first file. Here is the entire code I am running below.

```
 Naer_str= num2str(1000)

 disp(Naer_str)

 sigma_str = num2str(0.491)

 eval(['system(''sed -e "s~1111~${Naer_str}~; s~2222~${sigma_str}~;" OctaveChangeVarTestFile.IN > OctaveChangeVarTestFile_out.IN'');']);
```

The new input file is made, but rather than seeing the values 1000 and 0.491 as I anticipated the places where 0.491 and 1000 should be are blank. Running it in debug mode showed the follow error message (which I've seen a lot since I started to use Octave a few days ago, but I still don't really grasp what it means).

```
 error: invalid use of script in index expression
```

I have tried just inputting stuff into the Linux terminal like so:

```
 Naer_str=1000
sigma_Str=0.491
 sed -e "s/1111/${Naer_str}/; s/2222/${sigma_str}/;" OctaveChangeVarTestFile.IN > OctaveChangeVarTestFile_out.IN
```

This appears to work fine, so I assume that I must have made a grammar error either using system or eval, but I can't see it.

What is causing this error message? Why am I not seeing my anticipated output?

Comment: If you are going to vote this question down can I ask you to leave a comment. I am genuinely clueless as to what I've done wrong.

Comment: This doesn't really seem like a programming question, though I'm unfamiliar with the tools. That last part is the only reason I didn't downvote this or vote to close as off-topic.

Comment: Does Octave actually do `${…}` substitution into strings the same way bash does, but even inside single-quoted strings? If not, you're not sending the same thing to `sed` at all, you're sending garbage that it probably just takes as literal strings. So what you end up trying to eval is garbage.

Comment: Meanwhile, I don't know what Octave's `eval` does, but that `sed` invocation should output nothing at all, because you're redirecting its stdout to a file, so I don't see how it could have anything useful to evaluate. Unless `eval` is how you actually run the `system` command itself, not something you're doing on the result of calling it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It looks like all you have is a `system` call with a computed command.  You can pass a computation result as the parameter of `system()` already, you don't need, and should not use, `eval()` here.
2. The way to concatenate strings (character arrays) in octave is just horizontal matrix concatenation.  So instead of `'s~1111~${Naer_str}~'` (which as abarnert points out, gets interpolated by the shell which has no concept of octave variables) you can write `['s~1111~' Naer_str]` and octave will concatenate.
3. You don't need to reach outside octave to `sed` via `system()` for text replacement.  `strrep` and `regexprep` can do replacement on character arrays right inside octave (or Matlab).

Comment: I'm looking to edit a file outside of octave with this command. I've had a bit of a fiddle around with these suggestions but can't get around the fact that I need to pass the contents and not the name of a string into system. Using ['s~1111~' Naer_str].

I'm not trying to change text in a file that is outside octave. I can't see how you can conceivably do that uisng strrep or regexprep but maybe I'm just stupid. Thanks for the effort anyway. :)

Comment: @Reluctant_Linux_User: Either (1) read the file into octave, use `strrep`, and write it back out, or (2) use `system` and character array concatenation `['sed -e "s~1111~' Naer_str '~;"']` to build a command string that has the octave variable values already in it.

Comment: Option 1 is going to be messy, that's a really big file but it might work. Option 2 is exactly what I tried and that didn't work but actually reading your comment, I've realised what the problem is, we both missed the closing " in the sed statement. (Oysh, should have seen that!)

Comment: @Reluctant_Linux_User: The bits in my answer were not supposed to be a complete `sed` command-line, just enough to make the point *This is how you paste literals and variables together.*

Comment: @Reluctant_Linux_User: BTW, part #3 in my answer was because it wasn't clear whether these files came from octave data in the first place, or files from elsewhere.

Comment: As I say what you wrote in your first comment is exactly what I put (a few hours ago when I first saw your comment which was seconds after you wrote it) but looking at it when you've written it helped me see my earlier mistake. (I'm not trying to critique you coding skills which are obviously a lot better than mine!)

Comment: @Reluctant_Linux_User: I strongly suggest doing: `the_command = ['something' var 'somethingelse']; system(the_command);`  That way you can look at exactly what octave is sending to the shell

Comment: Remember that "The voice of experience" is just a nice way of saying "This so-called expert did it wrong so many times, a better way finally stuck in his brain"

Answer (score 8):

I don't know why specifically you're getting this error, but I'm 90% sure this won't do what you want:

```
eval(['system(''sed -e "s~1111~${Naer_str}~; s~2222~${sigma_str}~;" OctaveChangeVarTestFile.IN > OctaveChangeVarTestFile_out.IN'');']);
```

In bash, `${Naer_str}` inside a double-quoted string is a [variable substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/varsubn.html): it replaces the `${Naer_str}` with the value of the `Naer_str` variable in the string, before passing it along to the command. So, `sed`will get `s/1111/1000/;` as one of its commands.

But I can't find any reference to such a feature in octave's [Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Variables.html), [Manipulating Strings](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Manipulating-Strings.html), [Strings](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Strings.html), or elsewhere. Those characters are just going to be treated as literal characters. So, `sed` will get `s~1000~${Naer_str}~;` as an argument, which means it's going to produce a garbage script. It looks like the way you do this kind of thing in octave is by using printf-style formatting (as described all over the Manipulating Strings page).

Comment: Right so you think it is down to the use of the dollar sign? I thought that by using eval(['system('' INSERTCODEHERE'');']); That the line INSERTCODEHERE was effectively being done in the shell is this not correct?

Comment: @Reluctant_Linux_User: Yes, that line is being done in the shell… but the shell doesn't have access to variables you created in some other program (unless octave actually stores its globals in the process's `environ`, which I doubt).